# Update Clob value using SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update, clob

I have a table xyz
In which I have a clob (suppose a)

My clob structure is like below

```
<XML version ="1.0"?>
<properties>
   <property name ="tran_start_date">
   <value>1/1/2021</value>
   </property>
    <property name ="tran_end_date">
   <value>21/12/2021</value>
   </property>
   <property name ="accn_no">
   <value>12838372882</value>
   </property>
</properties>
```

Now I want to update the tran_start_date to 30/10/2021,
Trans_end_date to 30/10/2022,
And accn_no to 098765

How can I write a update query for this...I am using oracle database

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you have any sample code to share?

Comment: Better question - why are you using CLOB data type for XML data?

Comment: @mathguy, Does Oracle support something else to store XML data?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - the `xmltype` data type was introduced 20 years ago, in Oracle 9.0.1. You could have found that out yourself, a lot faster, with a trivial Google search, for example for the phrase "Oracle xml data type".

Comment: @mathguy, Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: By the way, is the `CLOB` value in your table supposed to be a correct XML document? (I am wondering if that's the reason you are storing it as `CLOB` and not as `xmltype`.) Your string is not a valid XML document - the preamble has two glaring mistakes in it, both at the very beginning. The `?` is missing after the opening `<`, and `xml` must be lower-case - you have it capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer a slightly different question - see if that helps.

In my comments under your question, I brought up two issues. First, your `clob` looks like an XML document, so it should be stored in a column of data type `xmltype`, not as a `clob`. (This is similar to storing dates as strings instead of the proper `date` data type.) Second, your "XML document" is not, in fact, a valid XML document, because its preamble has two major mistakes in it: the `?` is missing right after the opening `<`, and `XML` should be `xml` (lower case). Both are fatal mistakes that would not allow you to store that string as `xmltype`. (This, too, is similar to storing dates as strings, and having a string like `'31 February 2020'` - you can store it as a string, but if you try to store it in a `date` column, Oracle will immediately tell you something is wrong.)

In my solution below, I will keep the data type as `CLOB` - but I will store a valid XML document in it. Here is the code to create the sample table:

```
create table xyz (a clob);

insert into xyz values (
'<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<properties>
   <property name ="tran_start_date">
   <value>1/1/2021</value>
   </property>
    <property name ="tran_end_date">
   <value>21/12/2021</value>
   </property>
   <property name ="accn_no">
   <value>12838372882</value>
   </property>
</properties>'
);

commit;
```

Then here is one way to update it as you requested. I use `xmlquery` as the main tool; however, since your column type is `clob`, I must first convert it to `xmltype` (using the `xmltype()` constructor), and after the `xmltype` update is completed, I must convert the `xmltype` back to `clob`; that's what `xmlserialize` does. I use the `indent` option to `xmlserialize`; your input doesn't follow any systematic indentation, so the result will be indented slightly differently from the original. I hope that is OK. (As XML documents, that doesn't matter.)

```
update xyz
  set a =
    xmlserialize(document
      xmlquery(
          'copy $t := $x
            modify(
              (for $i in $t/properties/property[@name="tran_start_date"]/value
               return replace value of node $i with "30/10/2021")
            , (for $i in $t/properties/property[@name="tran_end_date"]/value
               return replace value of node $i with "30/10/2022")
            , (for $i in $t/properties/property[@name="accn_no"]/value
               return replace value of node $i with "098765")
            ) return $t'
            passing xmltype(a) as "x" returning content
      )
    indent size = 2)
;

commit;
```

This demonstrates the simplest way to update the values - the new values are hardcoded directly into `xmlquery`. This may be made more general by passing new values in the `passing` clause of `xmlquery`; exactly how to do that depends on how you would provide those runtime values to the `update` statement in the first place.

Check what's in the table now:

```
select a from xyz;

A                                                                               
------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<properties>
  <property name="tran_start_date">
    <value>30/10/2021</value>
  </property>
  <property name="tran_end_date">
    <value>30/10/2022</value>
  </property>
  <property name="accn_no">
    <value>098765</value>
  </property>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks and really appreciate the way you explained  , If possible can you explain a bit the code inside the xmlquery() function ?

Comment: @SauravKumar - not really. XMLQuery is a very large topic, and if you will need to manipulate XML documents (in any environment, not just in the Oracle database) you should learn it, but that's not something one can teach in a comment to an answer on a website like this. As a brief summary - the code here takes the input XMLtype object passed in as a variable named "x" and copies it into a new variable "t". Then it modifies t by replacing the three node values as you specified. The XMLQuery function then returns the modified version of the XML document. How much this helps you, I don't know.

Comment: @mathaguy that helped me a lot , thanks  -_- .